# Inspections.net runner in team city reports false positives

Tags: teamcity

We are using Team city for our continuous integartion purposes. The Resharper version used in our development environment is 7.0. The team city server's version is Team City 8.0.1 (build 27435) and it uses the Inspections.NET runner that comes as part of the installer to run the code inspections.

Our problem is that the Inspections.NET plugin in Team city reports some false positive c# compiler errors like :-
 Cannot resolve symbol 'string';
 Cannot resolve symbol 'void'

These errors are not reported when we execute our assembly locally both using the Resharper VS plugin and the Resharper 8.1 command line tool.

Any pointers on how this issue could be resolved would be helpful.

Cheers

Comment: did u make any progress on this?

Comment: We had to install VS2012 in our CI server for debugging purposes and after we installed VS2012, these issues seems to be resolved. Looks like there were some issues with the .NET framework 4.5 version that was installed in our CI server earlier.